# javascript change class of that button and other elements

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to buil a like/dislike system for a project and I'm having some trouble in the last part.

The like/dislike system is working, but I would like to have the button change automatically after the click (change class and icon).

This is working based on many rows and each of them is in this way (Like):

```
<button type='button' onClick='LikeDislike($row_data[id], $row_data[cat], 
$row_data[scat], $row_data[sscat], $_SESSION[user_id]);' class='btn btn-info 
pull-right btn-xs'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i></button>
```

In PHP I already made the code so the button shown at page load is to Like or Dislike based if there is a like or not.

The button to "Dislike" is the same, only changes the class of the button and the class of the :

```
<button type='button' onClick='LikeDislike($row_data[id], $row_data[cat], 
$row_data[scat], $row_data[sscat], $_SESSION[user_id]);' class='btn btn-
danger pull-right btn-xs'><i class='fa fa-thumbs-down'></i></button>
```

I have this code working to set the like/dislike, but I can't get a way to change the class of the button and the  class that's inside that specific button:

```
    $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'inc/like.php',
    data:'id='+id+'&cat='+cat+'&scat='+scat+'&sscat='+sscat+'&uid='+uid,
    success:function(msg){
        if(msg == 'err'){
            /** alert('Some problem occured, please try again.'); **/
            $.toast({
                heading: 'Error!',
                text: 'There was a problem processing your like.',
                position: 'top-right',
                loaderBg: '#ff6849',
                icon: 'error',
                hideAfter: 3500
                });
        }else{
        $.toast({
        heading: 'Success!',
        text: msg,
        position: 'top-right',
        loaderBg: '#ff6849',
        icon: 'success',
        hideAfter: 3500,
    });
        if(msg == "Like added."){
            alert(1);
            //** Remove Class btn-info and add class of button to btn-danger.
            //* Change class of the <i> element to fa-thumbs-down (inside that button)
        }else{
            alert(2);
            //** Remove Class btn-danger and add class of button to btn-info.
            //* Change class of the <i> element to fa-thumbs-up (inside that button)
        }

        }
    }
});
}
```

So, as I did it in PHP, after some likes/dislikes, some icons in the list are diferente (some are to like and other to dislike)

Please note that should be only effective for that button in specific and not in all buttons of that page.

I can't get an easy way to do it. Anyone could help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass your button to your function `LikeDislike` by using `this` keyword.

```
<button type='button' 
       onClick='LikeDislike(this, $row_data[id], $row_data[cat], $row_data[scat], $row_data[sscat], $_SESSION[user_id]);' 
       class='btn btn-info pull-right btn-xs'>
   <i class='fa fa-thumbs-up'></i>
</button>
```

after that, where you handle your ajax code, you can do the following :

```
function(ele, a, b, c, d) {
     $.ajax([...],
        success: function(){
           // Do whatever you like...

           ele.find('> i').removeClass('some-class').addClass('other-class');
        }
     );

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it, hope that would be the best way to do it.
For those that need this information, I left here the answer:

First I set the button an ID and the  class another one.
The button ID is set as 1,2,3,4...
The  elemento inside the button is set as 1_1, 2_1, 3_1..

Then, in the if statement (commented above):

```
            if(msg == "Like added."){
            document.getElementById(id).className = 'btn btn-danger pull-right btn-xs';
            document.getElementById(id+"_1").className = 'fa fa-thumbs-down';
        }else{
            document.getElementById(id).className = 'btn btn-info pull-right btn-xs';
            document.getElementById(id+"_1").className = 'fa fa-thumbs-up';
        }
```